# Spring Config profile file is not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-config

I've created this `application-local.json` into `src/main/resources`:

```
{
  "spring": {
    "datasource": {
      "url": "jdbc:postgresql://xxx:yyy/db",
      "username": "xxx",
      "password": "xxx",
      "driverClassName": "org.postgresql.Driver"
    },
    "profiles": {
      "active": "local"
    }
  }
}
```

By other hand, `apliication.yml`:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true

  profiles:
    active: local

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'

---

spring:
  profiles: local

server:
  port: 8092
```

Currently, I'm getting this message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: Is your `application-local.yml` a YAML or JSON file??

Comment: it's using json format. Sorry, it's a miswriting. The filename is `application-local.json`

Comment: Spring Boot only supports .properties and .yml/.yaml as sources of application properties. The only valid usage of JSON is providing configuration properties as a JSON string through `spring.application.json` application property. For more information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @tan9 can you please post your comment as answer. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Spring application runs, it load properties from value of *application.yml->spring->profiles->active*. Spring supports only *yml* and *.properties* file as a source.

So, in your case Spring will look for *application-local.**yml*** or *application-local.**properties*** to read profile specific property.

But here, you have defined property file as a *application-local.**json*** and that a reason why spring is not reading values and you are getting exception.

**Solution**
Create *application-local.**yml*** or *application-local.**properties*** and paste your content and try. It should work.

Here is sample DB configuration.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/_schema name_
spring.datasource.username=_username_
spring.datasource.password=_password_
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```